# Access data from another Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

now i have 2 Components 
1 - is just a drop down list v-select

```
<v-row align="center" >
  <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6" v-if="Compounds" >

  <v-select :items="Compounds" 
          v-model="selectedItems" 
          label="Select"
          item-value="id"
          item-text="name"
          v-on:change="selectedCompound">
</v-select>
{{ selectedItems }}
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

with method

```
     methods: {
          selectedCompound(h2o) {
         console.log(h2o);
         console.log("This is from Selected Compound");
                 },
```

and i call it in another page

```
          <div>
       <SelectCompound></SelectCompound>
         </div>
```

now i want to get the method "selectedCompound" and recall it on this page

so i can access the ID of it to reload the page when the user select another name from the v-select

Comment: You should read about [emitting events from components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events). You shouldn't need to call the function from a parent component.

Comment: do u want get the selected value from the child component? or just execute the method of the child component from the parent?

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo get the value from the child component to use it to reload the page with this id

Comment: any help please, i have been taking 3 days to solve it ant cant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are passed down, Events are emited up. If you want to communicate directly between the parent and child, you pass props from parent to child, and the child reacts to the change in value. If you *however* want the parent to react to changes the child component, you need to `emit` events.

Here is an example.

#### Child

```js
methods: {
   selectedCompound(h2o) {
       this.$emit('valChange', h2o)
   },
}
```

#### Parent

```html
<div>
    <SelectCompound @valChange="handleChange"></SelectCompound>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
   handleChange(h2o) {
       // handle here
       console.log('parent noticed change ' + h2o)
   },
}
```

You can also use a bus (like Vuex) to have all components communicate to a separate state manager, but it increases the complexity quite a bit compared to simple even emit.

Answer (score 1):

I made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cibercito/a8974t0y/) for you, using the `localStorage` as persistence if u need to reload the page, and emitting a event when any option of the select is selected, this event triggered is called `change` on the select tag, then just you have emit to the parent the value selected.
And using the life cycle method `created()` of `Vue` to init the value from the persistence.