# Access other component data and method from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components:

**ContainerSidebar.vue**

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="b-sidebar">
      <div class="change-image">
        <img
          :src="profile.avatar != null ? profile.avatar+'#'+Date.now() : 'https://redacted.com/avatar/no-image.png'"
          alt=""
        >
      </div>
      <h6>{{profile.email}}</h6>
      <a-menu
        :default-selected-keys="['1']"
        mode="inline"
        theme="dark"
        style="height: 100%;"
      >
        <a-menu-item key="1" style="margin-top: 70px" v-if="this.$route.path !== '/profile'">
          <home-icon icon-name="home" style="margin-right: 10px"></home-icon>
          <span>Beranda</span>
        </a-menu-item>
        <a-menu-item key="1" style="margin-top: 30px" v-else>
          <a-icon type="user" style="margin-right: 10px; font-size: 18px;"/>
          <span>Profil Saya</span>
        </a-menu-item>

        <a-sub-menu key="sub1" v-if="this.$route.path !== '/profile'">
          <span slot="title">
            <book-icon icon-name="book" style="margin-right: 10px"></book-icon>
          <span>Kelas Saya</span></span>
          <a-menu-item key="5" style="padding-left: 20px">
            <a-icon type="calendar" style="font-size: 18px"/>
            Jadwal Webinar
          </a-menu-item>
          <a-menu-item key="6" style="padding-left: 20px">
            <award-icon icon-name="home" style="margin-right: 10px"></award-icon>
            Sertifikat Saya
          </a-menu-item>
        </a-sub-menu>



        <a-menu-item key="2" v-if="this.$route.path !== '/profile'">
          <bag-icon icon-name="bag" style="margin-right: 10px"></bag-icon>
          <span>Katalog Saya</span>
        </a-menu-item>
        <a-menu-item key="2" v-else>
          <a-icon type="lock" style="font-size: 18px"/>
          <span>Ubah Sandi</span>
        </a-menu-item>

        <a-menu-item key="3" v-if="this.$route.path !== '/profile'">
          <file-icon icon-name="file" style="margin-right: 10px"></file-icon>
          <span>Projek Saya</span>
        </a-menu-item>
        <a-menu-item key="3" v-else>
          <a-icon type="question-circle" style="font-size: 18px"/>
          <span>Panduan</span>
        </a-menu-item>

        <a-menu-item key="4" v-if="this.$route.path === '/profile'" @click="logout">
          <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" style="margin-right: 13px"></i>
          <span>Keluar</span>
        </a-menu-item>

      </a-menu>
    </div>
```

The other one is **Profile.vue**, which the part i want to show is only the js part

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      page: 'profile',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    change_page(page) {
      this.page = page;
    },
  },
```

Consider the **ContainerSidebar.vue** is the parent component and the **Profile.vue** is the child component. How do i access the `change_page()` method which manipulate the `page` data variable on the Profile.vue internally? What i expected from this is to put the `change_page()` method on this part

```
<a-menu-item key="2" v-else>
   <a-icon type="lock" style="font-size: 18px"/>
   <span>Ubah Sandi</span>
</a-menu-item>
```

which uses `@click` event. I found a several example in here as such [Access data from another Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567257/access-data-from-another-component) but i still couldn't figure out the similarity as my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this with Vuex:

**store.js**

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Vuex from 'vuex';
    
    Vue.use(Vuex);
    
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        profile_page: 'profile',
      },
      mutations: {
        changePage(state, page) {
          state.profile_page = page;
        }
      },
    });
    
    export default store
```

And then commit the state on both parent and child component, i made a method with the commit statement inside the method:

```
    changePage(page) {
       this.$store.commit('changePage', page);
    },
```

and add a click event afterwards inside the html tag like this:

```
    @click="changePage("page_name")"
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need emit your parent method from child like this:

```
<parent-component class="container">
  <your-child-component @changePage="change_page"></your-child-component>
</parent-component>
```

And in your child component js code:

```
export default {
methods: {
    handleChangePage() {
        this.$emit('changePage', '/profile');
    },
},
};
```

After call handleChangePage inside child method will by executed parent method `change_page`

Comment: Which one of those codes put into ``Profile.vue`` and ``ContainerSidebar.vue``? Do the ``this.$emit('changePage', '/profile');`` part could change into ``this.$emit('changePage', 'page_name');``?

Comment: `this.$emit('changePage', 'page_name');` should be in Profile.vue component.
And yes you can change `/profile` to `page_name`

Comment: Should i put ``<parent-component>`` to ``ContainerSidebar.vue`` or ``Profile.vue`` ?

Comment: You Should put `<parent-component>` to `ContainerSidebar.vue`

Comment: What should the ``<parent-component>`` and ``<your-child-component>`` change into according to my example? It confused me a bit

Comment: Where is html template of your `Profile.vue` component?
Create fiddle example here https://codesandbox.io and provide link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-shannon-9ckm7 Here you go :)

Comment: @VickySultan create fork of your example and added emit function https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-haze-ww22z?file=/src/components/ContainerSidebar.vue